# Unity Internal_xxx functions

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm C++ developer and never done C# before. By curiosity, I was looking at the code of Unity and I do not sure to understand the following code:

```cs
[FreeFunction(Name = "GameObjectBindings::Internal_CreateGameObject")]
static extern void Internal_CreateGameObject([Writable] GameObject self, string name);
```

https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/UnityCsReference/blob/master/Runtime/Export/Scripting/GameObject.bindings.cs#L376

Looks like to me that the concrete code is implemented in outside file (extern), inside another class named `GameObjectBindings` but which seems not given inside Unity source since I failed grepping `Internal_CreateGameObject` and `GameObjectBindings`. What `FreeFunction` really means and why I could not find Internal_xxx functions ? Similar link https://forum.unity.com/threads/how-does-the-freefunction-attribute-work.857653/

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not the full [unity source code](https://blogs.unity3d.com/2018/03/26/releasing-the-unity-c-source-code/), it's just a repository with C# references. All c++ sources are still not accessible.

Comment: Ah ok thanks I got it ! I knew this document, but I was unsure of the meaning of "C# reference". Am I right if I can say that C# is a wrapper layer on C++ code and therefore FreeFunction(Name = "GameObjectBindings::Internal_CreateGameObject") refers to the C++ class ?

Comment: @Lecrapouille Yes, you are.